# Button with drawableLeft inside GridLayout

Tags: android, button, drawable, android-gridlayout

I have a GridLayout with 6 buttons inside :

[image]

When I try to set a drawableLeft property for the buttons, I have the following behaviors :
[image]

How to automatically scale drawable, so all the buttons are visible ?

The layout is :

```
  <GridLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#AFAFAF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <Space 
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1.5"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
    <Space 
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_columnWeight="2"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
    <Space 
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1.5"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />   
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PageHome_Learn"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/MenuLearn"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/TextPadding"
        android:text="@string/PageHome_LearnText"
        style="@style/Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PageHome_Piano"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/TextPadding"
        android:text="@string/PageHome_PianoText"
        style="@style/Button" />
    <Space 
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1.5"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/PageHome_SimpleGame"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/TextPadding"
        android:text="@string/PageHome_PractiseText"
        style="@style/Button" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/PageHome_AgainstTheClock"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/TextPadding"
        android:text="@string/PageHome_AgainstTheClockText"
        style="@style/Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PageHome_Scores"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/TextPadding"
        android:text="@string/PageHome_ScoreText"
        style="@style/Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PageHome_Settings"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/TextPadding"
        android:text="@string/PageHome_SettingsText"
        style="@style/Button" />
```

The style Button has no effects on the behavior.
I don't find any property to restrict drawable to button height.

Comment: Add your layout code please...

Comment: instead of button you can use the TextView and set the drawableLeft attribute to set the drawable

Comment: Same behavior with textview

Comment: This means your drawable are very large in dimension. If it is necessary to set drawable in xml only, then you have to use a ImageView and control the dimension. Or you can set the drawable from code and can control their dimensions

Comment: My drawable is a vectorial drawable (describe as scalar vector drawable (xml file))

Comment: @Geotinc try the answer I have given, the code part.

Answer (score 0):

Your drawable are very large in dimension. Because when you use drawableLeft type property, the android display that drawable in its full dimension.
If it is necessary to set drawable in xml only, then you have to use a ImageView to left of the button and control the dimension by giving width and hight to ImageView. 
Or you can set the drawable from code and can control their dimensions, like this:

```
Drawable btnOneDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(R.drawable.MenuLearn);
btnOneDrawable.setBounds(0,0,40,40);
buttonOne.setCompoundDrawables(btnOneDrawable, null, null, null);
```

**Update**
Try this in xml. Change the Button part with this in layout. Also you will have to set the outline drawable to this RelativeLayout instead of button.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/PageHome_Learn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="2"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/TextPadding">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPageHome_Learn"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/PageHome_LearnText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/MenuLearn"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnPageHome_Learn"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It's work when I use setCompoundDrawables, but I have to set the size...
How to take all the height of the button ?

Comment: are you giving height to your buttons? because you need to give same height as your button.

Comment: No, I don't give height, it's a gridLayout that define height... (By setting Row property)

Comment: Then I am afraid we either have to fix this from xml, or we need to add globalLayoutListener to the layout. This listener will let us know when the layout is inflated and then we get the Button height and can use it to set the Compound Drawables.

Comment: @Geotinc Try the updated answer if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have got from the following code and I think you want to achieve the same. Just using the Compound TextView.

[image: Grid layout screenshot]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_rowSpan="12"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:rowCount="3">

    <TextView
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:text="Button" />
    <TextView
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:text="Button" />
    <TextView
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:text="Button" />
    <TextView
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:text="Button" />
    <TextView
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:text="Button" />
    <TextView
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:text="Button" />
    <TextView
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:text="Button" />
</GridLayout>


// the code for ButtonStyle in the styles.xml file
<style name="ButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:drawableStart">@drawable/ic_library</item>
    <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/ic_library</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_columnWeight">1</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```